# how free internet proxy works

Tags: proxy, internet, isp

I tried to get free internet bypassing my mobile network's ISP using a proxy setting in my mobile. I got the instructions in some trick I read and it actually works. When I browsed the proxy page, it opened.

1) How my mobile network ISP is allowing packets to proxy?

2) I read that they create an ssh tunnel between my machine and the proxy but there is no application on my machine to forward http data into ssh tunnel
so then how http traffic is redirected to ssh.

Try searching "free internet airtel proxy" for better understanding.

Comment: Not only is this "trick" against the T&Cs of your ISP, but it is not a security question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and Foremost the "trick" you are using is an exploit of your ISP's poorly planned infrastructure. As such it is most likely just as **illegal** as joining your neighbors WiFi because they left the default password enabled.

### Why it works:

Your ISP is only monitoring HTTP/HTTPS traffic either via a transparent proxy of there own, or deep packet inspection.  For whatever reason, they are not monitoring (or more likely monitoring but not charging) for other forms of network traffic ie VoIP services.  This means if you setup your device to tunnel its traffic through to an external proxy via sock5 or socks5 over ssh ... your packets will be logged as non-HTTP(s) traffic and thus you will not be charged (yet).

### Why this is Dangerous:

The "FREE" proxy you are using is most likely doing **[nefarious](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT4YJn7oVI)** things.  Your ISP works with in the limits of the law ... this means they will not do things like steal your sessions, rewrite client-side javascript, steal your credit-card information ... etc.  I would recommenced watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT4YJn7oVI) for examples of what vulnerability you are exposing yourself to by doing this.

Also, as I mentioned already ... use of this exploit is **illegal**.  There is a very high likelihood that your ISP is tracking this bandwidth and while it is not currently charging you for it ... could retroactively charge you for it in a future bill.

Comment: the question is how my internet traffic is being redirected to be sent through ssh

Comment: I am aware, the problem is that the setup you referenced does NOT use ssh ... it sends them through a SOCK proxy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS it is possible to go through SSH to your own SOCKS proxy but that is not what is being shown in setup you referenced

Comment: ok the proxy is socks proxy but how is the request made in web browser sent to tcp socket of ssh

Comment: the setup you referenced has nothing to do with SSH.  It simply shows you how to configure the network settings of your device to route all http/https packets to an external proxy (via the SOCK protocol).  It is possible to port forward a SOCK server over SSH but that is not what is being shown.  In terms of SOCK ... your phone/browser support it passively.

Comment: can you explain what happens if my proxy is socks and request is http

Comment: see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#HTTP

Comment: but you said for packet to be non HTTP "tunnel its traffic through to an external proxy via sock5 or socks5 over ssh" now you are saying my phone is not using ssh

Comment: which means that it is happening via sock5 ... and ssh is not involved in this case ... that is why I used an "or"

Comment: ok i did not pay much attention sorry and thank you for great answer